# React on Laravel with vite error expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, laravel-8

newbie coder here. I just finished my React on Laravel with vite code, and I ma trying to load it to a shared hosting called Orangehost. Tried browsing videos and docs in the internet to no avail. I am receiving an error,

" Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."

My file setup is, the React will handle all of the front end and will only use Laravel as server. No blade file. Used web.php and controller only for Laravel.

Below is my .htaccess,

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /react/index.html [QSA,L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

AddType application/javascript js
```

---

React index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link
        rel="icon"
        type="image/png"
        href="/react/src/assets/images/title.png"
    />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>MCabaluna</title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Urbanist:wght@100;400&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet"
    />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Upon load, it will render main.jsx but the content is the index.html. Not sure what would be the correct one.

main.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom'
import './index.css'
import router from './router.jsx'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
  <RouterProvider router={router}/>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

Thank you in advance!

- Tried changing the .htaccess.
- Check available information in the internet.